# docker-compose resolve containers names on bridge from container on host network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dns, multicast

I have several containers in docker-compose: some on a custom bridge network & one on a host network because it has to be able to work with multicast.

Is there a way for container on host network to resolve names & be able to communicate with containers on the bridge network not using their ports.

On Kubernetes it's solved by dnspolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet

Thanks.

Comment: You can create a network and add them all in that network. But by not using port, do you use default port for services? Like MySQL 3306, web-server 80/443, etc.?

Comment: @Saeed what do you mean create a network? Some of them are already on the bridge docker network but one container cannot as it must be on host network. I doesn't matter which ports I use, read about ClusterFirstWithHostNet

Comment: Kubernetes's networking system is different (and much more complex) than plain Docker's.  Docker "host networking" mostly disables the container networking stack entirely and your container runs directly on the host interfaces; from that point, if you want to call back to containers, you need to use their published ports in the same way a non-container process would.

Comment: @Maze that's exactly what I try to avoid: using ports! I've seen guides on using weave with docker-compose & maybe smth like that or just plain iptables tricks may help.